# Query by 2 or more fields on GraphQL

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

Suppose if we want to query multiple fields on GraphQL, how to do that ?

```
{
  book(id:"123",name:"book1") {
    id,
    name,
    authors{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Also, how to filter out subfield, like author based on name??

```
{
  book(id:"123",name:"book1") {
    id,
    name,
    authors(name:"author1"){
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I have found this article, but just wanted to know is there any better way .
https://www.yld.io/blog/query-by-2-or-more-fields-on-graphql/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are building a GraphQL server and want to know how to filter on sub-field.

Depending upon the server library you are using, you world want to write a "Field Resolver" on the parent "Book" type. Field resolver is called once for each resolved parent so you will have reference to the resolved parent type(`Book` in your case) as well as arguments to field(`name: "author1"`) and then you can resolve it.

You might also want to use [dataloader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader) since one database call to resolve author sub-field per parent field can cause flood of database queries.